# Qt Creator/CMake not updating files per second in compile output

Tags: qt, cmake

Sorry for what is probably a stupid question.  I upgraded my Linux box recently and got the latest Qt Creator/CMake combination.  I noticed that the files/sec in the compile output isn't being updated - it always shows 0.0/sec.  Is this calculation provided by Qt Creator or CMake?  My guess was Qt Creator because the current file / total files still works and that is for sure coming from CMake.  It seems like a trivial feature, but it quickly helps me determine if .o files are being supplied from ccache or if they're being built from source.

Thanks for any input.  My previous install used CMake 3.10.x and QtC 4.5.x and the new uses CMake 3.10.3 and QtC 4.6.1.

[image]

NOTE: I also installed QtC 4.5.2 and tried that and still saw 0.0/sec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These calculations are provided by the build tool script, i.e. makefile or ninjafile. The IDE has nothing to do with it, and you should be able to reproduce this behavior from command line. Go to the build directory at the command line, and start `make -j` or `ninja`, depending on which tool you've configured your Qt Kit to use.

Comment: Thanks!  I use ninja, but when I build on the command line it only seems to provide the current file / total files part, not the files per second.  Let me try reverting to an earlier version of Ninja....

Comment: It looks as though Ninja uses an environment variable called NINJA_STATUS that is empty on my machine.  Looking at that now..

Comment: Ultimately it looks like CMake in my previous installation was setting NINJA_STATUS and in my current setup is not.  Ninja has for some time supported the calculated files per second output if properly configured via that env variable.

Actually, the display is there it's just the values that are zero.  I suppose this could be a regression in Ninja...

Comment: Sorry to waste anyone's time.  I grabbed the latest Ninja from their github page and everything works again.  Looks like 1.7.1 had a regression.  1.8.2 works great.  Kuba I'll say you answered my question - you definitely pointed me in the right direction.